# remove shared edge after the union of two polygons

Tags: arcobjects

I have two polygons that are next to each other (left image). After performing a union of the two polygons, I have a single polygon with outlines similar to the left image. What I am looking for is a way to remove the shared edges of the two polygons, as shown on the right. I am working with arcobjects (.net) and arcdesktop 10.1. Hopefully there's a nice built-in method to achieve this. Thanks.

[image: Left image is what I am getting after a union. Right image is what I want.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work with the [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) tool. It merges two polygons and remove any two edges that are near each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a nice built-in method - you're looking for the [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Members/004700002t69000000/) tool.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. I realized that the edges aren't matching up exactly, there's a gap between the edges of the two polygon.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the ArcObjects help, this may help you.

[**Creating a union of several polygons**]
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000009t000000.htm

Comment: Thanks, the link is how I got the union of the two polygons, but the outline of the polygon from the union still shows the outlines of each individual polygon.